# Override mylocation button in android Google maps api v2

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying yo override Google map's default my location button to display "GPS is not enabled"  message if the user is pressing the mylocation button when gps is not enabled. How can i do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

register for the mylocation click using `setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener` and in `onMyLocationButtonClick ()` show your message.

Comment: GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener is not listed there in my eclipse.There is everything like GoogleMap.onMarkerDragListener() but not onMyLocationButtonClickListener() .  :(

Comment: I just try and it is not listed in mime either. This following said that it is added 2 days ago by a project member https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4789

Comment: So if i update the GoogleMap class will i get GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener() ? Did you solve in your case ?

Comment: Yes, update using Android SDK Manager and rebuild google_play_services_lib.

Comment: really appreciate your answer it is save my time

Answer (score 0):

i can add the code based on Hoan Answer

```
 map.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Good", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

you can make what you want in the function